# Paste the link in javascript

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

**Hi everyone!**

I have script in Spring MVC application which adds an entry in the table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#saveSubject').submit(function (e) {
        $.post('/university/subjectAdd', $(this).serialize(), function (subject) {
            $('#subjectsTableResponse').last().append(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + subject.title + '</td>' +
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"c:url value=\'/subject/update/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>' + Update + '</a>'+'</td>'+
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"c:url value=\'/subject/delete/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>' + Delete + '</a>'+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>'
            );
        });

        clearInputs();

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

But when you add the recording error takes related link

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Update is not defined
```

My table:

```
<div class="tableSubjects">
    <table border=2 bgcolor="#C1CDCD" id="subjectsTableResponse">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><B>Предмет</B></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${subjectList}" var="subject">
         <c:if test="${subject.deleted eq false}">
                <tr>
                 <td align="center">${subject.title}</td>
                  <td align="center">
                    <a href="<c:url value='/subject/update/${subject.id}' />">Update</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href="<c:url value='/subject/delete/${subject.id}' />">Delete</a>
                </td>
             </tr>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>

enter code here
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: why tagged `java` instead of `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

- If `Update` and `Delete` are supposed to be literal strings, they should be enclosed in quotes.
- In order to have `subject` passed as an object rather than a string of JSON, you have to pass a data type of `'json'` to `$.post`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#saveSubject').submit(function (e) {
        $.post('/university/subjectAdd', $(this).serialize(), function (subject) {
            $('#subjectsTableResponse').last().append(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + subject.title + '</td>' +
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"c:url value=\'/subject/update/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>Update</a>'+'</td>'+
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"c:url value=\'/subject/delete/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>Delete</a>'+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>'
            );
        }, 'json');

        clearInputs();

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but nothing has changed

Comment: I suspect that the error in the screening of characters in the link

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the adjusted code? What URLs do you want your link references to point to?

Comment: The code is the same. I note that if I remove the addition of references to the JavaScript response, everything works without error

Comment: I want to insert the link Ajax response   <a href="<c:url value='/subject/delete/${subject.id}' />">Delete</a>

Comment: doesn't work :( I added a code table. Prompt correctly I wrote link in response  '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"c:url value=\'/subject/delete/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>Delete</a>'+'</td>'  ?